# Unable to remove gray borders around images?

Tags: javascript, css, image, border, styling

For some reason, I am unable to remove a gray border from around my images. I am using Javascript to insert them, if that helps you. Thanks!

[image: Click here to see a screenshot.]

```js
var helloContainer = document.getElementById('hello-container');

  var helloImg = new Image(20, 20);

function imgRepeater(e) {

  var helloCount = e;

  helloImg.className = 'hello-img';

  helloContainer.innerHTML = '';

  if (e != "0") {

    for (var i = 0; i < helloCount; i++) {

      helloContainer.appendChild(helloImg.cloneNode(true));

    }

  }
}

imgRepeater(10);
```

```css
.hello-img {
  width: 20pt;
  height: 20pt;
  background-image: url("http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/1a/01/1a010db8ee92e120595b5b8977a8328e.png");
  background-size: contain;
  border: 0 !important;
  outline: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="hello-container"></div>
```

Comment: Your code does not reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused because the image element requires a "src" attribute. The grey border is part of the placeholder that the browser will display in place of the image. To remove it you should either set the "src" attribute of the image instead of applying it with CSS, or create a different element such as a span.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your container (helloContainer) is the element with the grey background. Right-click on the element and use 'Inspect Element' to look at the active CSS.